# Getting mapping error for @OneToMany

Tags: java, hibernate

I am new for Hibernate and i have such a big problem with it. I have two classes: Client and Reservations. Client is one-to-many relationship with Reservations

Client.java

```
  @Entity
  @Table (name="Clients")
  public class Clients  {   
  @Id
  @GeneratedValue 
  @Column(name="id_client")         
private int id_client;  

public Clients()    
{}
@OneToMany(mappedBy = "client")         
private Set<Reservations> reservation;

@Column(name="name")
private String name;

@Column(name="last_name")
private String lastName;

@Column(name="phoneNo")
private String phoneNo;

public Clients(String name, String lastName, String phone)
{
    this.name =name;
      this.lastName = lastName;
       this.phoneNo = phone;
}


 //  setters , getters
```

Reservations.java

```
 @Entity
 @Table (name="Reservations")

 public class Reservations  {

@Id
@GeneratedValue
@Column(name="id")
private int id_res;

    @ManyToOne
@JoinColumn( name = "id_client" )
private Clients client;

@Column(name="date_start")
private Calendar dateStart;

@Column(name="date_end")
private Calendar dateEnd;   

@Column(name="price")
private BigDecimal price;


public Reservations() {}

public Reservations(Clients client, Calendar dateStart, Calendar dateEnds)
{       
    this.client = client;       
    this.dateStart = dateStart;
    this.dateEnds = dateEnds;
}

   //  setters , getters
```

My problem is: i get error

Failed to create sessionFactory object.org.hibernate.AnnotationException: Use of @OneToMany or @ManyToMany targeting an unmapped class: model.java.hibernateApp.Clients.reservation[model.java.hibernateApp.Reservations]

But despite i saw a lot of similar topics i can't fix this problem, Thanks for any help.
I learned from: http://viralpatel.net/blogs/hibernate-one-to-many-annotation-tutorial/

Comment: please show your imports and your persistence.xml or hibernate.cfg.xml.

Comment: But my annotations are good? because I think there is an error..

Comment: you should check that the classes are registered in the persistence.xml or hibernate.cfg.xml AND that the @Entity annotation is from the package  javax.persistence .entity

Comment: Also, rename your classes to Client and Reservation. An instance of Clients is **one** Client, so there's no reason to call the class Clients.